# How to build our own profiler in java?

Tags: java

Want to create customized profiler for java. In search of that got to know about the Hprof tool ... for creating profiler the i reffered the details given...but it is creating a profiler which is of my requirement...then when searched again another link

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jip/?ca=dgr-lnxw07JavaProfiling

and
http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-profiling-under-covers

I followed the steps i created a project by copying the program for profile agent code from the first link..then a manifest file was created 
Version No:1
Xcomment: Main will be automatically detected

I replaced the second line with 
Line given in that link then pasted that file in the src folder of the Netbeans project
cleaned and build & created a .jar file.

but java -javaagent:Vc.jar classfile
when executed in command prompt errors are coming ...
Errors
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoclassFoundException : C:/documents/Main.class

at java.net .URLClassLoader
...
..

I needed get only the cpu time for each class i used and the cpu time of each method in each class... what shall I do?

Error opening Zipfile or manifest missing
error occurred during initialization of vm agent library failed to init instrument in command prompt

Comment: I think you need to take a step back and slow down. Learn your Java basics very well before you attempt anything so complex as writing your own profiler.

Answer (score 0):

[Visual VM](http://visualvm.java.net/index.html) is an excellent open source profiler. If, for some reason, its not good enough for your needs, you might be able to customize it.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at http://www.spf4j.org, it is a simple sampling open source profiler implemented in java, which works well, and it can be easily used for continuous profiling

Answer (score 0):

See *ClassFileTransformer*:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html

This can be used to transform the bytecode of any class when loaded, allowing you to inject profiling calls.

This is where I learned it from:
http://blog.javabenchmark.org/2013/05/java-instrumentation-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

For error

> Error opening Zipfile or manifest missing error occurred during
>   initialization of vm agent library failed to init instrument in
>   command prompt

use following as VM arguments :

```
-javaagent:"<FileSystemPath>\<Agent Jar file name>.jar"
```